# Comparison of US HPC Resources

Tags: parallel-computing, hpc

I was wondering if anyone knows about the differences between the large HPC resources available to US researchers. I am currently using a startup allocation (through the NSF GRFP) on XSEDE but was thinking about helping my PI apply for a research allocation. However, I was wondering what the other options are. I have heard of Blue Waters, how does it differ from XSEDE in terms of resources, queue wait times, etc? Are there any other similar resources that I should consider?

(BTW, I am surprised that if I google Blue Waters vs XSEDE there's no nice blog post about this!)

Answer (score 1):

Blue Waters is a single system, and XSEDE is a consortium that has many systems available.